# I am using latest version of webview_flutter plugin. I need to change the initial url of the webview and need to add token for new url

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

```
`  WebViewWidget(

         controller: WebViewController()

        

                  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
                  ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.white)
                  ..setNavigationDelegate(
                    NavigationDelegate(
                      onProgress: (int progress) {},
                      onPageStarted: (String url) async {

                      },

                      onPageFinished: (String url) {
                        print("url is +=++++++++++++ $url");


                      },
            onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {

                      },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {

                                                                                
                          NavigationDecision.navigate;

                        }   else{
                          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                        }

                      },


                    ),
                  )
                   
                  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(
                    
                      ApiUrl.vendorDashBoardUrl  + Get.find<AuthService>().apiToken
                     ),
                     )
                )
```

`

The case is i added an initial url in `..loadRequest` with token . It's working fine. Now In that webview there is a button which redirect to another url. Now all I need to add the token with that newly generated url from that button. How can I solve it in webview_flutter latest version?